# xsd:extension, xsd:restriction, and use="prohibited"?

Tags: xml, xsd, complextype

So I have this code snippet over here:

```
<xs:complexType name="TT1">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="A1" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="A2" type="xs:integer" use="optional"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TT2">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:restriction base="TT1">
            <xs:attribute name="A1" use="prohibited"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

and the question is: **Is this whole thing valid?**

The only thing I see is `TT1`:

```
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
```

which is nonsensical since the types for `A1` and `A2` are supposed to be integer.

Is there anything else that I can't see?

P.S. I'm not quite sure about the sense of the use="prohibited" in `TT2` but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which is nonsensical since the types for A1 and A2 are supposed to be
>   integer.

No, it's not nonsensical.  `A1` and `A2` are attributes and their types can be defined independently of the type of the content of their associated element (`TT1`), a `xs:string`.

> P.S. I'm not quite sure about the sense of the use="prohibited" in `TT2`
>   but I don't know why.

If this attempted override makes you uneasy, it should.  Overriding a required attribute by switching it to being prohibited is not allowed.  So, no, this XSD snippet is not valid.